# Log Changes in a video (e.g. mp4) content in C#, or other language

Tags: video

I would like to create an application which has a video file input (for example mp4). The video content is a static picture (a bird and nest). I would like to create a log message (timestamp) when anything happens in the video (the bird flies in/out the nest).

Could you please advise me of an existing application?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The company I work for has a [multimedia library](https://www.leadtools.com/sdk/multimedia-suite) that contains a [motion detection filter](https://www.leadtools.com/sdk/multimedia/filter-motion-detection).

You can use the filter either with pre-recorded video files like MP4, MPEG, AVI and others, or you can use it with live video capture using devices like webcams.

There’s a free evaluation edition you can try before deciding whether to buy the toolkit, which [you can find here](https://www.leadtools.com/downloads?category=mm).

There’s a demo project that uses the filter in [this forum post](https://www.leadtools.com/support/forum/posts/t9042-). Although the post is old and the project was built with Visual Studio 2008, the same C# code can be used with the latest version of LEADTOOLS and newer versions of Visual Studio.
There’s also free technical support through email and chat if you need help with the toolkit while evaluating or after buying.